# Refused to display 'https://www.accountkit.com/...' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, iframe

I'm getting this error when I try to load the modal from Account Kit.

I'm using the same solution implemented in a previous code that I did. So it is weird that it's not working.

It's not working in develpment either in production (heroku).

even tried the next code, but didn't work.

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
    "X-Frame-Options" => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```

my `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

  <!-- HTTPS required. HTTP will give a 403 forbidden response -->
  <script src="https://sdk.accountkit.com/es_LA/sdk.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.6.2/firebase.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
```

I'm using RubyMine.
`ruby 2.4.1`
`rails 5.0.6`